# Turn off space confirmation on GUI elements JAVA

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm writing a simple application with JButton-s and I want to run another action on space press. But when I hit space, the button that was pressed as the last is pressed too. How can I turn space confirmation off? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Remove the key binding associated with the buttons which is linked to the space key

Comment: thanks, for me button.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0, false), "none"); worked